# Trying to update a label inside a grid using time-delayed character typing

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried asking this question earlier, but I think this is a better way to ask.

To start:

I am using Windows, and Python 3, with `Tkinter`.

I am trying to, on button press, update the first row of my grid, namely `page_label` to add a single character over time, and I'm currently attempting this using `time.sleep()` inside a `for` loop.

This works extremely well when using `sys.stdout.write()` without a gui, but I couldn't manage to get anything to write to a label directly, rather than my terminal.

So, I figured I should be able to use the `.config` from `tkinter`, and just update the label for each character, with a small time delay between each update.

However, when I run the following code, the time delay stacks and the update to the config doesn't run until the end.

So, when I first run the app, I get my initialized text in `page_label`.
Then after what I assume is the completion of the `for` loop, the final new statement displays as the label updates.

I would be happy with either my current workaround to work, or if there is a nice, clean way to get `stdout` to write to the label directly, I'd be extremely pleased.

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageTk, ImageDraw
import json

root = Tk()
root.title('actiread test')
root.iconbitmap("C:\\Users\\nicho\\Desktop\\Code Puzzles\\actiread\\actireadico.ico")
root.geometry("800x800")

#button triggering time delay text

def get_input():
    words = ""
    statement = "I need this to print in time delay"
    for char in statement:
        words = words + char
        page_label.config(text = words)
        time.sleep(0.2)

#creating updating label

page_label = Label(root, text = "I want to start with an introduction")

#creating button
entry_button = Button(root, text = "Start", command = get_input)

page_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
entry_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = 10, sticky = EW)

root.mainloop()
```

Please ignore the useless imports, I have more to add to the program that I believe will require them.

If it helps, What I'm trying to accomplish will eventually require user inputs that will be saved for later use, and I'll be moving through several versions of this to move through a storyline.

TIA!

Comment: Your problem can be solved quite easily by just adding `root.update()`, but that is not the _correct_ solution to the problem. What you need to do is use `root.after()` properly,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, when you use `time.sleep()`, it blocks the tkinter event loop from processing events and your GUI is stuck since it cannot process events. The right way to do this, is by using `root.after(ms, func, *args)` method which will repeat a function after a given amount of time.

```
def get_input(words="",count=0): 
    statement = "I need this to print in time delay"
    if count < len(statement): 
        words += statement[count] # Index and get the current letter and add to the current string
        page_label.config(text=words)
        
        count += 1 
        root.after(200,get_input,words,count) # Call the function passing arguments words and count
```

And another hacky way around this is to use `root.update` inside the for loop to force tkinter to process the events, but this is not a good practice.

And a relatively easier solution might be to use global variables instead to understand better:

```
count = 0
words = ""
def get_input(): 
    global count, words

    statement = "I need this to print in time delay"
    if count < len(statement):
        words += statement[count]
        page_label.config(text = words)
        count += 1

        root.after(200,get_input)
```

Do note that 200 passed on, is the time for delay in milliseconds, which is same as 0.2 seconds that was passed onto `time.sleep`

Comment: Thanks so much! Works like a charm. Now, I need to figure out how to make the statement something variable. I'd like to use user inputs and customize text to have their input somewhere in a sentence. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm guessing' I'll likely have to make the statement variable an argument to pass into the get_input function, or a similar function anyway.

Comment: @NBacon You will have to fetch the user input inside the function, prolly